# iOS Safari does not recognize url schemes after user cancels

Tags: ios, iphone, safari, mobile-safari, url-scheme

I'm noticing strange behavior in Safari recently.

I register a url scheme for the my app, and enter `myapp://` into Safari.
This launches my app immediately.

Then I go back to Safari, and enter `myapp://` into Safari again,
this time it prompts me **"Open this page in "myapp"?"** Cancel or Open.

My app will launch if I tap on open, and subsequent attempts the same alert shows. If I try tapping on cancel, my app will not launch. which is expected.

However, if I enter `myapp://` into the URL bar again, I'm prompted **"Cannot Open Page" "Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid."**

This will fail in the same way for all subsequent attempts, until I kill Safari and re-start it, or open another tab.

This is the same behavior with Youtube and Evernote. my guess is that Safari cached the URL as an invalid URL when the User taps on cancel. Is there official documentation on this behavior?

Bbserved in iOS 8.1.2 and iOS 6.1.3

Comment: Any update on this? I can't seem to find any decent way to re-enable my app URL scheme.I had to reset the device settings to make it work again :-(

Comment: i had a same problem, make sure in the info.plist you should have written "appurl" not "appurll://"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In 9.1 the issue still exists. The solution for me is just restarting safari (swipe up to clear it from background).

Comment: Restarting Safari didn't work for me. After restarting the problem comes again if user presses cancel. Did it get fixed for you after restarting ?

Comment: @ChiragBhutani  It's a consistent bug. What I meant was the prompt would come out if you restart Safari. But if the user keep pressing cancel, of course it would fail again.

Comment: I have noticed one more thing. If I host a simple html page on my server with a button redirecting to url scheme then it works fine even if I press cancel but if i use javascript in my webpage then after pressing cancel the problem occurs. Any idea regarding this?

Comment: Still happens on iOS 12.0.

Comment: Still happens on iOS 15.5. :-(

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. Once cancelled, it would give that error.

What I did was sending an extra parameter with a timestamp, so Safari would not cache it. So after the last param, I added a foo param with the number of milliseconds since midnight January 1, 1970. I use as3, but this should be readable for all developers:

```
var foo:Number = new Date().time; //The number of milliseconds since midnight January 1, 1970
var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url+"&foo="+foo);
```

Comment: nice idea. maybe I'll try this some time

Comment: The OAuth2 `state` parameter can also serve this purpose, since it should normally be constructed with a unique value that can help prevent forgery attacks.

Comment: a cache buster on the tab did not work for me.  once the user clicks `cancel` that tab will no longer honor the custom url scheme.

Answer (score 2):

relaunching the safari app, or opening a new tab solved this problem

Answer (score 0):

When you call your url add a unique value such as timeStamp to your url call

```
double currentt = [[NSDate new] timeIntervalSince1970];
NSTimeInterval differ= [[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:currentt] timeIntervalSinceDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1296748524]];
NSLog(@"differ: %f", differ);
NSString *url =[NSString stringWithFormat: @"https://thisisawebsite&timestamp=%f", differ];
```

Will always then see the popup until you click "Okay"

Comment: Can you clarify your `thisisawebsite` url please?  Because as its shown above it is an improper url...you need a `?` between the domain and the parameters.  I suspect maybe this is why its working for you because using a cache buster does not work for me.  What @UrbanMetro answered with is correct, the issue is tab specific and cache busting does not work on that tab once the user clicks `cancel`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding following code in AppDelegate solved my problem, hope it works for you too.

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    let notification = Notification(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "AppNotificationLaunchString"), object: nil, userInfo: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.url:url])
    NotificationCenter.default.post(notification)
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My observation is that it seems to be a setting associated with the Safari tab. If you open a new tab, the url scheme works.

Cancel disables the url scheme and saves the setting into the tab. If you swipe away Safari or even restart the phone, Safari will restore the tab and it still won't handle the scheme. However the url scheme works if you open a new tab.

I suppose that for consistent behavior, you would want to somehow get a new tab opened before the url scheme is used.

Comment: On Safari ios 15.3.1 - the same behavior happens.  Its tab specific.  And cache busting does not work on the tab once the user cancels just one time.