# URL scheme is not opening up the app for users but works for me

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0, url-scheme, branch.io

My app initiates an OAuth2 flow and and uses URL scheme for the redirect URI to redirect users back to my app.

When I install the app from the app store and start OAuth2 flow, it successfully opens the app at the end.
But on users devices it doesn’t recognize the URL scheme and prompts an error message : Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid.

I am using Branch.io for universal links but I don't think that could affect anything and I can't think of anything else that could break url scheme.

Does anyone have any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: Take a look at this Stack Overflow answer from a Branch Engineer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47455960/safari-cannot-open-the-page-because-the-address-is-invalid-appearing-when-acce

Comment: Thanks for the comment but I already read that when I was looking for a possible solution. Answer suggests to use universal links but technically url scheme should also work. It works for me. I am wondering why it will fail for some users

Comment: Did you had a chance to look into this thread - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27739442/ios-safari-does-not-recognize-url-schemes-after-user-cancels?